# Pass variable to form-element twig file on contact form only

Tags: 8, forms

I want to pass a variable to the form element twig file only when the contact form is viewed.
However the approach below does not work. The variable isn't available in the template file.

```
function module_test_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    // Determine Contact Form
    if($form_id === "contact_message_feedback_form")
    {
        $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE; // Disable Preview Button
        $form['is_contact_form'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that in fact the correct $form_id?

Comment: Yes preview button is hidden. So I did it the right way? Maybe my twig file is something wrong